# nested table rows sort in angular 5

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular5, nested-sortable

i want to Sort nested table-rows, but did not found any angular library for that, below is my code.

```
<table class="table table-bordered tabledesign">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>
                Sr #
                <span class="sort-icons"></span>
            </th>
            <th class="cursor">
                Menu Name
                <span class="sort-icons"></span>
            </th>
            <th class="text-center" *ngFor="let permissionListNew of permissionList;">
                {{permissionListNew.name}}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="treeViewTemplate; context:{ $implicit: menusList }">
        </ng-container>
    </tbody>
</table>
<ng-template #treeViewTemplate let-menusList>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let parameter of menusList;let i=index;">
        <tr [ngStyle]="{'background-color': parameter.color ? parameter.color : '' }">
            <td class="text-left">
                <a *ngIf="parameter.child_menus?.length > 0" (click)="parameter.expand = !parameter.expand">
                    <i class="fa plus-icon" [ngClass]="parameter.expand ? 'fa-minus-square-o' : 'fa-plus-square-o'"></i>
                </a>
                <i *ngIf="parameter.child_menus?.length <= 0" class="fa fa-circle"
                    style="font-size: 10px; padding-right: 3px;color: #f68c1f;"></i>
            </td>
            <td>{{parameter.sr_no}}</td>
            <td class="text-left">{{parameter.name}}</td>
            <td class="text-center" *ngFor="let permissionListNew of parameter.permissions;let permissionIndex=index;">
                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input"
                    [name]="'permission_' + parameter.row_id + '_' + permissionIndex"
                    [checked]="permissionListNew.is_permitted" [(ngModel)]="permissionListNew.is_permitted">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <ng-container *ngIf="parameter.expand && parameter.child_menus?.length > 0" class="pl-4">
            <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="treeViewTemplate; context:{ $implicit: parameter.child_menus }">
            </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

> using this i am not able to drag & drop the table rows, below is the image of code UI

[image]

> **using which library i can Drag & Drop(sort) table rows UP & DOWN for angular 5**

Comment: you can use jqueyUI for that !!

Comment: @NishargShah any other library for angular ?

Comment: material angular is best for that